# Restify + TypeScript:

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, restify

I have a Node.js + Restify application, written in TypeScript. I try to load the Crypto module (https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html):

```
import * as crypto from "crypto";
```

When I compile the script, I get following error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'crypto'.
```

When I use JavaScript instead of TypeScript, it works fine:

```
var Crypto = require('crypto');
```

Other modules which I load at the same place works fine, for example:

```
import * as bcrypt from "bcrypt";
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: is it part of your configuration?

Comment: Yes, in my package.json: "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1", ..... }
When I compile my typescript (with an error) and I run the javascript, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the crypto dependency, as it has been moved into NodeJS... without that dependency, the import works fine for me in a `njsproj` file in Visual Studio:

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
```

If you are having more general type problems or are in an IDE or project type that doesn't understand Node, check you have the typings as a dev dependency, for example `@types/node`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i have solved with this dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "3.0.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
     ...
  }
```

after that, i could import the module with no errors

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
```